# Filtering snowflake view subquery

Tags: sql, filter, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a view definition in a Snowflake database that involves a subquery with some join conditions. When I select data from the view and apply certain filters to the main query, the filters don't seem to apply to the subquery. As a result, all partitions from the subquery are scanned instead of only those where the filter conditions should apply. How can I modify the view definition to ensure that the filters are correctly applied to the subquery and only relevant data is fetched?
Simplified Query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS (
    SELECT
        main_table.id,
        main_table.name,
        main_table.date,
        main_table.hour,
        subquery_table.additional_info
    FROM main_table
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            sub_id,
            date,
            hour,
            additional_info
        FROM subquery_table
    ) subquery_table 
ON main_table.id = subquery_table.sub_id
);
```

When selecting data from the view, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM my_view 
WHERE date = '2023-07-27'
and hour = 0
```

I noticed that all partitions are scanned from the subquery, but I would like the filtering to apply there as well.

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you!

Comment: You can add a join on the date columns as well.

Comment: It doesn't work, al partitions from the subquery table will be scanned, even if the join is on the date columns

Comment: Why are you LEFT JOINing to a SELECT statement rather than directly to the table?

Comment: The subquery from the left join has additional logic that is not included in my simplified example. I'm selecting only the records with the most recent date by partitioning on a few id columns.

Comment: So is the simplified version also not pruning as you expect? If you change the view to only select from the main_table does it prune correctly? How many records are there overall in your main_table and how many per day/hour? Snowflake may only prune if the performance benefit justifies it

Comment: Selecting from main_table is partitioned as expected.
My problem is that when I want to select data from the view, for a given date and hour, I noticed that these filters are passed onto the main_table only and I would like for the subquery to be filtered as well.

Comment: To do that you would need to expose those subquery columns in your view and explicitly filter on them when you query the view. Alternatively, it may work if you explicitly joined on those additional columns in your view definition. Currently there is nothing in either your view definition or your query that is filtering on these subquery columns so there is no reason for the subquery to be filtered

Answer (score 0):

if you view is complex enough and/or you SQL over the view is complex, or both, or the phase of the moon, "pushing down" the filters does not happen. We experienced this for years, and how we solved it was to use [SQL UDTF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-tabular-functions) to pass the filters "into the view" so they where always, "pushed down".

Given we controlled all of the access layer SQL generation, we altered our SQL generation layer to use the functions over the views.

```
select <complexity>
from view_name
<more complexity>
```

goes to:

```
select <complexity>
from table(udtf_name(filter_parameter_to_push_down))
<more complexity>
```

This worked wonderfully.

so for your function it would look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udtf_my_view(date_filter date, time_filer time)
    RETURNS TABLE(id number, name text, date timestamp, hour time, additional_info variant)
    AS
    $$
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        a.date,
        a.hour,
        b.additional_info
    FROM main_table as a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            c.sub_id,
            c.date,
            c.hour,
            c.additional_info
        FROM subquery_table as a
        WHERE c.date = date_filter 
            and c.hour = time_filer 
    ) as b  
ON a.id = b.sub_id
);
```

```
SELECT * FROM table(udtf_my_view('2023-07-27'::date, 0)
```

Noe this will do a full scan of `main_table` because you have no filter on that, but `subquery_table` will be correctly limited. Assuming this is the problem to are trying to solve.

And also allowed forcing of our multi-tented customer data to use one function (that was schema version aligned) instead of a view per customer, thus removing the need for millions of views replace/creations on customer facing schema changes.